# Checking that input is an integer between 1 and 3 - Python

Tags: python, string, validation, python-3.x, integer

I want to be able to check that an input is an integer between 1 and 3, so far I have the following code:

```
userChoice = 0

while userChoice < 1 or userChoice > 3:
    userChoice = int(input("Please choose a number between 1 and 3 > "))
```

This makes the user re-enter a number if it is not between 1 and 3, but I want to add validation to ensure that a user cannot enter a string or unusual character that may result in a value error.

Comment: Do add the [tag:python-3.x] tag if you are using python3 as `input` has been changed from 2 to 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Catch the [`ValueError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html?highlight=valueerror#ValueError):

> Raised when a built-in operation or function receives an argument that
>   has the right type but an inappropriate value

Example:

```
while userChoice < 1 or userChoice > 3:
    try:
        userChoice = int(input("Please choose a number between 1 and 3 > "))
    except ValueError:
        print('We expect you to enter a valid integer')
```

Actually, since the range of allowed numbers is small, you can operate directly on strings:

```
while True:
    num = input('Please choose a number between 1 and 3 > ')
    if num not in {'1', '2', '3'}:
        print('We expect you to enter a valid integer')
    else:
        num = int(num)
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively try comparison of `input` in desired results, and `break` from the loop, something like this:

```
while True:
    # python 3 use input
    userChoice = raw_input("Please choose a number between 1 and 3 > ")
    if userChoice in ('1', '2', '3'):
        break
userChoice = int(userChoice)
print userChoice
```

Using `Try/Except` is a good approach, however your original design has a flaw, because user can still input like "1.8" which isn't exactly an integer but will pass your check.